# Promises dando problema

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JS, e comecei a ver sobre Assincronismo, e cheguei em uma aula. Fiz como foi mencionado,mas não aparece nada na aba network do browser,nem retorna erro no console,aqui vai o código:

```
  var minhaPromise = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/diego3g')
        xhr.send(null)

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhr.readyState === 4){
                if (xhr.status === 200){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
                } else{
                    reject('Erro na requisição')
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

minhaPromise()
    .then(function(resolve){
        console.log(resolve)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.warn(error)
    })
```

Depois tentei usar a bibliotexa axios,mas deu na mesma,nada acontece:

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/user/diego3g')
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.warn(error)
})
```

Comment: Não cheguei a testar com o axios, mas já no seu primeiro exemplo, funcionou normalmente, todos os dados do retorno da API do github foram exibidos no console.

Answer (score 1):

Eu rodei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Você está usando o console de algum browser, correto? Como você está usando `console.warn` no caso da Promise ser rejeitada, pode ser que nada esteja aparecendo pra você porque a opção warning do seu console esteja desabilitada. Tente habilitar ela ou mudar o `console.warn` para `console.log`.